# Maybe a Virus on Android?

Tags: web-browser, android

On a Android Device one of the Internet Browsers (OperaMini) disappeared, it just appeared again when I used the preinstalled Browser when asked to choose which Browser to use for searching (preinstalled or OperaMini).

The system was not slow and there were no new installed apps recently.

Beyond a symptom that the scrollbar in the internet browser sometimes jumps, there was nothing else.

Could it be a malware or perhaps the Anti-virus app, that hid the OperaMini app ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've said, I think it's very unlikely that you've been hit with any sort of malware unless you've visited any sketchy websites before-hand (embedded stage-fright and whatnot).

As for what caused the error, I can't be sure without more information. But again, I find it very unlikely that malware is at fault.

Comment: I don't have tools to check it properly. The Antivirus I have it's of course good, but maybe sometimes it needs something like reverse-engineering.